# WebRTC not adding datachannel in SDP answer

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I can successfully create a datachannel by calling `peerConnection.createDataChannel("some/label")` and then `peerConnection.createOffer()`, in which case the datachannel appears in the SDP offer (i.e. there is an `m=application` there).

But now I want the *other* peer to create the datachannel, and therefore have it appear in the SDP answer. Same thing: I call `createDataChannel` before `peerConnection.createAnswer()`. Except that this time, I don't see an `m=application` in the SDP answer.

Shouldn't it be possible to create a datachannel from the second peer, and shouldn't it appear in the SDP answer?

My code looks like this:

```js
if (type === 'offer') {
    peerConnection.createDataChannel("some/channel");
    peerConnection.createAnswer().then(createdDescription).catch(errorHandler);
}
```

I tried with both Firefox and Google Chrome, and I have the same issue, i.e. I don't see an `m=application` in the SDP answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SDP follows an "offer-answer model" described in [RFC 3264](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3264). If the offer did not negotiate datachannel, the answer can not contain an additional m-line negotiating it.
The answerer will, after sending their answer, have to send an additional offer with a datachannel m-line.
The negotiationneeded event *may* fire to indicate this is required.

Comment: Oh that's interesting! I tried it but got "DOMException: Cannot create offer in have-remote-offer", so I thought I could not send a new offer after the exchange...